# Fast method to get row indices of selected cells in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, performance, datagridview

I want to obtain a list of the row indices of selected cells in a DataGridView.

I was previously using `SelectedCells` to get this information, but this takes around 40 seconds when there are 2 million rows and all are selected.

```
this.SelectedCells
    .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
     .Select(c => c.RowIndex)
```

On [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ha5xt0d9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says that `SelectedCells` is slow for large grids, but apart from the special case where all cells happen to be selected, does not offer many alternatives. What if all but 1 row/cell is selected?

Is there a faster method?

Comment: what is you question clearly?

Comment: He wants a faster alternative to SelectedCells

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack, but I eventually reverted to using reflection to access the private field `DataGridView.individualSelectedCells`, which is a linked list of the selected cells. This is much faster than accessing `DataGridView.SelectedCells`, though obviously less robust.